# Why does System.getenv() return null when run from a .bat file?

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm writing a Java program that should only execute a method when I'm connected to my work PC with RDP. For that, I'm using `System.getenv("sessionname");`

When I run it in command prompt, I get the expected value of `RDP-Tcp#5`. When I run it in a `.bat` file though, it returns `null`.

My code is yet pretty simple:

Java:

```java
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getenv("sessionname"));
    }
}
```

Batch:

```batch
java test
@pause
```

I've read about environment variables being the problem, but I haven't changed or used them in either one of the programs.

So why is that?

Comment: one would guess there is no "sessionname" environment variable in your batch environment

Comment: @AndrewT How do I set them for this specific environment?

Comment: check if it's there for starters, update your batch to print the list of environment variables:

set | more

java test

pause

Comment: @AndrewT I've done that, "sessionname" is not listed. How do I add it?

Comment: you can use "set sessionname=somevalue" in the same batch file if you want to add it manually. judging by the variable name it's related to windows RDP, so it's probably auto-set when you connecting as an RDP session